# How to fetch remote branch properly?

Tags: git, github

I had to delete my git branch and now need to fetch that remote branch.

I did the following steps as I've seen someone's post here.

```
git clone <repository-address>
git fetch origin
git checkout -b <branch> origin/branch
```

But I am not sure if it worked as expected. Here's my output for git branch -a

```
* my-branch (GREEN)
  master (GREEN)
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master (RED)
  remotes/origin/my-branch (RED)
```

If anyone help me understand whether my-branch will be matched with the remote one or not. If not, I'd appreciate it if you could explain this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone help me understand whether my-branch will be matched with the remote one or not

Probably. But it's impossible to be certain from the info you have given. To find out, say

```
git branch --all -vv
```

If the listing for my-branch also mentions origin/my-branch, you're all set. If it doesn't, just set the upstream yourself.

Comment: I really appreciate it!! One question though, when I do git status. I see FETCH_HEAD (RED) in untracked files. Which is weird, because I've never seen this before. Any idea why this shows up? @matt

Comment: Any time you fetch you get a FETCH_HEAD, I don't know why it would show up as file you can _see_. So maybe you did some weird thing. Take a look and see what it is and where it is!